# How can I style this following form to Inline form?

Tags: website-design, css, html

SEE the link: http://samuelgeorgeo.com/cc/NEWDESIGN/

I have a site based on Twitter Bootstrap. I have two main elements on the page, the bottom one is a horizontal form. I would like the bottom div to be horizontally centered, matching the div above. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want the form to be center and in horizontal form. Could you help me?

Comment: you have hard-coded some stuff. Bad idea.

Comment: @boblet re-opened!

Comment: cheers. Probably not a question that is very useful for others, so I hope the asker appreciates it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using bootstrap, and there would be more elegant ways of solving it, but here is one little hack.

You have some styles hard-coded into the html, and I would strongly suggest you remove those and put them into your css. Further; I would recommend that you create your own stylesheet, and use that for overrides from the Bootstrap stylesheet.

Anyway, here goes my little hack. As I said, it is not very elegant, but it is simple:

This is what you have; this is the structures of your divs:

[image]

Here is what you have to do: 
in html, change

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
```

to

```
<form class="form-inline container" role="form">
```

change

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
```

to

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And then removing the guiding frames:

[image]

Comment: Samuel: it would be good if you accept and upvote this answer, should it have solved your problem. It is good for you, me and the entire community.